# Iterate JSON object

Tags: javascript

I have the following JSON Object:

```
{
  "a1_1_on" : "on",
  "a1_1_thr" : "",
  "a1_2_on" : "on",
  "a1_2_thr" : "",
}
```

and I want using a for loop to check the fields for example:

```
for (var i=1; i<2; i++) {
    //alarm
    var al = 'ai_' + i + '_on';
    //alarm threshold
    var althr = 'ai_' + i + '_thr'

    //console.log(form_infos.al);

    if(form_infos.al == "on" && form_infos.althr == "") {
        alert("Alarm for Analog " + i + "is on and you did not specified a threshold. Please specify a threshold before submittiing");
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it shows `undefined` if I do `console.log(form_infos.al)`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - It's neither, because it's invalid. The `=` characters should be colons.

Comment: @JamesAllardice yep. ( didn't notice. I jsut started to see it wasn't a string at all.

Comment: But how guys? If I do `form.infos.a1_1.on` it returns `on`

Comment: Yes quys consider it a JSON object. I did a mistake with `=` instead of `:`

Comment: Check http://www.json.org/js.html explains all you need

Comment: Use `form_infos[on]` instead of `form_infos.on` because in the first case the `on` part will be treated as a variable and the lookup will go to `form_infos['ai_1_on']` or whatever.

Comment: you can validate your json at jsonlint.com The json object is still invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.

**First** of all, In JSON ':' is used between key and value, so it has to be

```
{
  "a1_1_on": "on",
  "a1_1_thr": "",
  "a1_2_on": "on",
  "a1_2_thr": "",
}
```

by the way this is not JSON, but a simple Javascript Object. JSON would be the String representation of that Object.

**Second**, your string to index the elements has a typo, you have

```
 "a1..."
```

in your Object but you use

```
 var al = 'ai_' + i + '_on';
```

in your code (i instead of 1)

**Third**, al is not an subobject of form_infos, but a variable containing a string. To access a subobject with a string index use

```
form_infos[al]
```

instead of

```
form_infos.al
```

That's it

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery for this. For example:

```
var obj = {
  "a1_1_on" : "on",
  "a1_1_thr" : "",
  "a1_2_on" : "on",
  "a1_2_thr" : ""
}

$.each(obj,function(i,value) {
    ...
});
```

[jQuery each reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)